# Parse React - Observe Objects created by Parse.User.current()

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, reactjs

I'm using the excellent [parse-react](https://github.com/ParsePlatform/ParseReact) library to get Parse and ReactJS to work together nicely (n.b I've only been playing around for a few hours so apologies if I've misunderstood any of the basics of reactjs).
All was going well until I wanted to query a table for all objects created by the current user (Parse.user.current())

The observe method works correctly on load and the view is rendered with the correct objects (the objects created by the current user). However if I mutate the data and add a new object then the view doesn't re-render.

Abstracted code:

```
module.exports = React.createClass({
    mixins: [ParseReact.Mixin],
    getInitialState: function() {
        return {
            selected: null
        };
    },
    observe: function() {
        return {
            places: (new Parse.Query('Place'))
                        .equalTo('user', Parse.User.current())
                        .descending('createdAt')
        };
    },
    clickHandler: function(event) {

        var id = event.target.id;
        if (id === 'new') {
            ParseReact.Mutation.Create('Place', {
                name: 'New Place',
                user: Parse.User.current()
            }).dispatch();
        } else if(id.indexOf('Place:') === 0) {
            this.setState({
                selected: id.substring(6)
            });
        }

    },
    render: function() {

        var that = this;
        var navItems = this.data.places.map(function(place) {
            return (
                <UserNavItem id={place.id} key={place.id} label={place.name} selected={that.state.selected === place.objectId} onClick={that.clickHandler}/>
            );
        });

        return (
            <ul>
                {navItems}
                <UserNavItem id='new' label='+ New Place' onClick={this.clickHandler} />
            </ul>
        );

    }
});
```

If I remove the part of the query that specifies the user:

```
.equalTo('user', Parse.User.current())
```

Then it works; new place objects appear in the list when added.

Has anyone got any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Am I using Parse queries incorrectly? It always seems strange that getting the data pertaining to the current user is a bit of a pain when this seems like such a common use case?

Thanks!

Comment: Does this work when you are not using Parse.User.current()?  For example if you are using a Parse.Object version of that user?

Comment: I think the User.current() method returns a User which 'extends' a Parse.Object but could be wrong. I've tried using the user objectId in the query/mutation to no avail. Also the create mutation does work (a new object is created in the table and appears when I refresh the page) which makes me think the problem could be elsewhere. p.s. thanks for the response!

Comment: No problem, I seen this come through on GitHub and I wasn't in front of my machine to try and recreate the issue, but I thought I would try and lend some assistance.  I have seen some weird things with the Parse.Use.current() object where it seems like it does not retain the authenticated state and returns null.  That that might be happening.

Comment: Ah yes maybe. To be honest I can return the entire dataset for now (without filtering by user) for development purposes. Hopefully as ParseReact gains traction cleverer people than me will put there minds to the problem and come up with a solution. I'm still blown away how good ReactJS and Parse are so this hasn't dampened my spirits :D

Comment: I agree!  Let me know if you find a solution to this as I will be developing a feature that uses the same sort of logic that you have in your example very soon.  I am @agnosticdev on Github too and I am subscribed to the Parse+React repo.

Comment: @AgnosticDev will do!

Answer (score 3):

The solution is to call the `.refreshQueries()` method of the component when the new object is successfully created in Parse as described [here](https://github.com/ParsePlatform/ParseReact/blob/master/docs/api/Mutation.md#relation-field-mutations).

My updated example:

```
            ParseReact.Mutation.Create('Place', {
                name: 'New Place',
                user: Parse.User.current()
            })
            .dispatch()
            .then(function() {
                this.refreshQueries();
            }.bind(this));
```

Thanks very much to [Joshua Sierles](https://github.com/jsierles) over on the ParseReact github repo for pointing me to the solution. If you are on SO Joshua I'll give you the credit if you post your answer here :D